# Creating step numbers dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I hate manually typing steps numbers.  So I was trying to write a small function to find some text and replace it with generated step numbers.
And I can't use the ol/li tags because I have multiple groups on the page.  So I need to add an "a", "b", etc after the number.

My HTML:

```
<span class="grouping" v="a">
----My first step
----This is another
----And another
</span>
<br/>
<span class="grouping" v="b">
----second group
----second group 2
</span>
```

This is my jquery (but it doesn't replace the ---- to a step number).

```
$(function(){
    $(".grouping").each(function(){
        var val=$(this).attr("v");
        var counter=1;
        $(this).find(":contains('----')").each(function(){
            $(this).text("("+counter+val+") ");
            counter++;
        });

    });
});
```

So eventually, I want the webpage to finish like this:

```
(1a) My first step
(2a) This is another
(3a) And another

(1b) second group
(2b) second group 2
```

Comment: `$(this).find(":contains('----')")` is never going to find anything.  The `this` is the grouping, and the nested children are text nodes, which the find will not find

Comment: Offtopic: your step numbers are in reverse.  No doubt you have good reason for this, but it looks odd.  Would normally be 1a,1b,1c then 2a,2b,2c  or a1,a2,a3 / b1,b2,b3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to split the text at `'----'` and concat with the values (added `br`s for lisibility so I used `html` instead of `text`):

```js
$(function(){
    $(".grouping").each(function(){
        var val=$(this).attr("v");
        var arr = $(this).html().split('----');
        if(arr.length > 1){
            var str = arr[0], i, l = arr.length;
            for(i = 1; i < l; i++){
                str += '(' + i + val + ') ' + arr[i];
            }
            $(this).html(str);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="grouping" v="a">
----My first step<br>
----This is another<br>
----And another<br>
</span>
<br/>
<span class="grouping" v="b">
----second group<br>
----second group 2<br>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. For each of the groupings, get the inner html and split it by newline
2. If it starts with '----', replace it with an incrementing line number, and append the `v` value.
3. Put the html back into the grouping.

```js
$('.grouping').each(function(index, grouping){
  var lines = grouping.innerHTML.trim().split("\n");
  var lineNumber = 0;
  var v = grouping.getAttribute('v');
  
  lines.forEach(function(line, index){
    if (line.startsWith('----')) {
      lines[index] = '('+ (++lineNumber) + v +') '+ line.slice(4);
    }
  });
  
  grouping.innerHTML = lines.join('\n');
});
```

```css
.grouping { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="grouping" v="a">
----My first step
----This is another
I should not have a line number.
----And another
</span>
<br/>
<span class="grouping" v="b">
I also should not have a line number.
----second group
----second group 2
</span>
```

Comment: If the line doesn't start with the prefix, would an "else" be needed to just add the line to the "lines[index]"?

Comment: If it doesn't start with `----` the line remains unchanged.  No need to modify it.  @dev4life

Comment: @dev4life added some non `----` lines to show you it works.

Comment: Oh I see it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` will not work. You should get text of the element and `split()` it and then change it using `map()` and `replace()` and reset `text()`

```js
$(function(){
    $(".grouping").each(function(){
        
        var val=$(this).attr("v");
        var counter=1;
        let lines = $(this).text().split('\n');
        lines = lines.map(ln => {
          if(ln.includes('----')){
            ln = ln.replace('----',`(${counter}${val})`)
            counter++;
          }
          return ln;
        })
        lines = lines.filter(ln => ln !== '');
        $(this).text(lines.join('\n'));
    });
});
```

```css
.grouping { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="grouping" v="a">
----My first step
----This is another
----And another
</span>
<br/>
<span class="grouping" v="b">
----second group
----second group 2
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest wraping those groups into some kind of tag. for example, span:

```
<span class="grouping" v="a">
 <span class="grouping-item">My first step</span>
</span>
```

And so on, it will be easier and faster to target those elements.

Then create one function to search through those new tags

```
$(function(){
  // This will create those numbers
  function createNumbers(el) {
    const mainGroup = el.attr("v");
    const children = el.children(".grouping-item");
    let i = 1;
    children.each(function(){
      const currentText = $(this).text();
      $(this).text( '('+i+mainGroup+')' + currentText );
      i++;
    });
  }
  $(".grouping").each(function(){
    createNumbers($(this));
  });
});
```